# MVC Java AngularJS OracleDB

Tags: java, angularjs, model-view-controller

i dont know if this question is already there...
I am Soft Eng in Testing. I have a background of selenium (consequently Java).
I am taking on new ventures now-a-days
i want to explore coding side of SDLC. Though i have coded in Java but for Testing. I do have a coding background before -- i am good at C/C++/Java/SQL and UNIX Shell scripting.
I wanna create an application using MVC. on front end i wanna use Angular JS, business logic in Java and my data in OracleDB.
Can anybody please give me a very basic framework say e.g. there are just two textboxes on html page using angularJS , then in java i add two numbers entered in it and save them in db.
I just need that little start so that i can get started with it.
I know i am asking for spoonfeeding, but trust me i just need that little start that's all. rest i'll expore and develop. I just do not know where to start from in terms of setting up the environment for MVC, how does AngularJS -- Java -- Oracle will communicate. i searched on github but there doesnt seem to be any basic one.....

Thanks a tonne....

Comment: This question will not get a good response, SO is not a site for recommendations. That said I look at the MEAN stack, its just javascript front to back and the data is stored as BSON (just like JSON). angular is MV* meaning its MVC or MVVM

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), it's not a lightweight framework though it provides great functionality for what you're looking for. It supports OracleDB and works great with angularJS due built in json support. Also setting up a project takes only a few minutes with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).

So for example of saving those two numbers would look something like this (I did not test the code):

Html:

```
<form ng-controller="MyController" ng-submit="saveNumbers()">
    <label>Number one</label> 
    <input type="number" id="number-one" name="number-two" ng-model="numbers.one"> 

    <label>Number two</label>
    <input type="number" id="number-two" name="number-two" ng-model="numbers.two"> 

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Angular controller:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.numbers = {};
    $scope.saveNumbers = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/numbers',
            data : $scope.numbers
        })
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```
public class Numbers {
    private int one;
    private int two;

    public Numbers() {
    }

    public getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public getTwo() {
        return two;
    }
}
```

And a controller:

```
@RestController
public class NumberController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/numbers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveNumbers(@RequestBody Numbers numbers) {
        numbers.getOne();
        numbers.getTwo();
        // Save the numbers to your db
    }
}
```

You can also find more examples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples).